# Command "symfony console messenger:failed:show" not working

Tags: symfony, symfony-console, symfony-messenger

- I am working the [Symfony Fast Track Chapter 18.3](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/18-async.html#retrying-failed-messages)
- Configuring the Messenger Configuration (*config/packages/messenger.yaml*):

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        # failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async: 
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    auto_setup: false
                    use_notify: true
                    check_delayed_interval: 60000
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    multiplier: 2
            failed: 
                dsn: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
            App\Message\CommentMessage: async
```

- The Messenger daemon is started
- But when I run the following command I get the error Message below:

```
jpmena@jpmena-300E4A-300E5A-300E7A-3430EA-3530EA:~/CONSULTANT/FASTTRACK/DEV/guestbook$ symfony console messenger:failed:show

                                                                      
  There are no commands defined in the "messenger:failed" namespace.  
                                                                      
  Did you mean this?                                                  
      messenger
```

- What is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: What do you have in result if you just execute "symfony console messenger"?

Answer (score 3):

I think your forget to remove comment on "failure_transport" line

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        failure_transport: failed <-- remove comment here
```